# rte_eth_dev_count_avail() from the DPDK API returns 0

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to use the DPDK api and trying to get a count of the number of ethernet devices available for use by the application running on top of DPDK. For this purpose I make use of the rte_eth_dev_count_avail() method provided by the DPDK api, but it returns 0 even when I see devices bound to DPDK compatible device drivers.
Here is the output of ./usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status

[image]

As you can see, I have multiple device drivers bound to DPDK compatible device driver, so not sure why this is happening.

I have also added the output for ldd [binary] as mentioned in the comments.

[image]

I am adding the output of the command egrep "SHARED|IGB_PMD|EM_PMD" $RTE_TARGET/.config

[image]

Output for ./usertools/dpdk-pmdinfo.py -d /usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids [binary] | grep -i "PMD NAME"

[image]

Comment: Your porblems could one of the reasons 1) Build in shared library mode, but forgot to add option `-d` with appropriate PMD. 2) Build with custom make file, forgot to add the right library in LD_FLAGS for ethdev constructor. 3) disabled e1000 or EM for IGB PMD build in `.config`. Also share the result of `ldd [binary]` and `cmd line arguments`

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have updated the question with the output of ldd [binary]

Comment: thanks for the update, looks like you are using static build. Now we are down with 2 scenarios. please run egrep "SHARED|IGB_PMD|EM_PMD" $RTE_TARGET/.config, run application with `-w 0000:01:00.1 -w 0000:01:00.2 -w 0000:01:00.3` . share application `cmdline options`. If using custom make file run make -n if it is bash script echo the cmd

Comment: I was waiting for update for running with whitelist options, cmdline, and whether you were running with DPDK makefile or custom. Let me simplify things for you, what is output for `./usertools/dpdk-pmdinfo.py -d /usr/share/misc/pci.ids examples/l2fwd/build/l2fwd  | grep -i "PMD NAME"` you should find either `IGB|EM`

Comment: substitue `l2fwd` with your `binary`

Comment: @VipinVarghese I get an import error when trying to run dpdk-pmdinfo.py as shown in the image above

Comment: you have install missing tools `apt-get install -y python3-pyelftools python-pyelftools` please check the `import module error in python`

Comment: updated the question @VipinVarghese

Comment: same here update by running `update-pciids`, then `find /usr/ -name pci.ids`. pass the path on your system

Comment: if the binary is created with the relevant libraries you should get ```# ./usertools/dpdk-pmdinfo.py -d [your path]/pci.ids [binary]  | grep -i "PMD NAME" | egrep -i "IGB|e1000"
PMD NAME: net_e1000_igb_vf
PMD NAME: net_e1000_igb
PMD NAME: net_e1000_em
```

Comment: PMD NAME: net_e1000_igb_vf
PMD NAME: net_e1000_igb
PMD NAME: net_e1000_em

Comment: please also share your command-line options, and result with running with options `-w 0000:01:00.1 -w 0000:01:00.2 -w 0000:01:00.3 --log-level=pmd,8`

Comment: I only have X710 cards, and not I350 to reproduce locally

Comment: Updated the question. Do not get the output that you mentioned.

Comment: please accept and upvote as the problem is solved as explained in the answer via live debug.

Answer (score 1):

@Ashwin looks like your static build does not have RTE_PMD for `IGB` or `EM`. this can be due to `custom makefile` or `presence of pre-installed DPDK pkg`. Please check your environment.

Absence of IGB|E1000 leads to `i350` not being found.

Edit: analyzing `https://github.com/tcp-acceleration-service/tas/blob/master/Makefile` there libraries are missing. Please add `-lrte_pmd_e1000 -Wl`

you can edit `DPDK_PMDS` to reflect `e1000` too.

Comment: I have a pre-installed DPDK pkg. Can't I run multiple DPDK versions? Not a requirement though, I can have a single version running on the server, in which case how do I fix the issue?

Comment: you should share the details `custom makefile` or `copied makefile from DPDK example`. In a pre-installed scenario, try modifying `ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists libdpdk && echo 0),0)` to `ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists libdpdk && echo 0),1)`

Comment: This is the link to the custom makefile:  https://github.com/tcp-acceleration-service/tas/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: @AshwinKumar as suggested, the problem has been solved by adding the PMD to build flag. Please accept and upvote the answer/